# proof that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^ \infty f(x) e^{-\epsilon |x|}$ = $\int_{-\infty}^ \infty f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, riemann-integration

$f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R $ is a function. given that for all a<b $\in \Bbb R$ , $f \in \mathbf{R}([a,b])$ (Riemann integrable). Also the integral $\int_{-\infty}^ \infty |f| $ $< \infty$ exists and its finite.

- first question : show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ , the integral $ \int_{-\infty}^ \infty f(x) e^{-\epsilon |x|}$ exists and its finite.
- second question : show that  $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^ \infty f(x) e^{-\epsilon |x|}$ = $\int_{-\infty}^ \infty f(x)$ .

**I solves the first question** but failed to solve the second one ! , can someone help .

Comment: Your question will very likely be better received if you show some of your own efforts in solving the second part, as it is it's pretty likely that it will be closed for failing to meet MSE guidelines. I can't help too much unless I know you've given it some effort, but if you need a quick hint I think you'll find [Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) very useful here

Comment: i told you . i tried solving it , but i failed . i used the sandwich method and it didn't work!

Comment: thanks for  the hint

Comment: Trust me I believe that you tried it, but you should still include your attempts. People tend to be a bit kinder here if they know you're trying, also knowing what you've tried and what you have in mind helps us give you better help. (for example if you have a good idea we can help you find how to proceed)

Comment: Some context is needed. Does $\mathbf R([a,b])$ mean we're talking about Riemann integrals here?

Comment: @Bungo yes , its Riemann integrals

Comment: In that case it's probably helpful to break the integral into three integrals, over the intervals $(-\infty, a)$, $[a,b]$, and $(b, \infty)$, where $a$ and $b$ are chosen so that the first and third integrals are small. For the middle integral, show that $f(x) e^{-\epsilon|x|} \to f(x)$ *uniformly* on $[a,b]$ as $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

Answer (score 1):

First take $-\varepsilon =-\frac{1}{n}$ and notice that since $e^{-\frac{1}{n}|x|}\leq1$ then $|f(x)e^{-\frac{1}{n}|x|}|\leq|f(x)|$, and by hypothesis is integrable, so we can use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, and if we call $f_n(x)= f(x)e^{-\frac{1}{n}|x|}$ then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{-\frac{1}{n}|x|} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) $$

Because $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ trivially.

Comment: The OP is using Riemann integrals. It may not be correct to assume that he/she knows the Lebesgue theory yet.

Comment: he answered a comment about lebesgue measure and dont mention a thing about it, so i supossed he could use it

Comment: Yeah, it would have been better if the original question had included the context. I edited so it at least mentions that these are Riemann integrals.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was the intended method, the dominated convergence theorem is just screaming to be used here